# osm2pgsql osm_timestamp is NULL

Tags: postgis, osm2pgsql

I use osm2pgsql to load osm.pbf Data into a PostGIS database.

One objective is to store the osm_timestamp into a column.
The flag "-x" is used in the cmd code.
With the following line in the mapfeatures.style, the osm_timestamp is recognized:

```
node,way    osm_timestamp   timestamptz(0) linear
```

This results in a column "osm_timestamp", but all lines are "NULL".

I can't find a solution, because everything but NULL is expected.

Comment: Does -x mean the same as `--extra-attributes`? Do you use `--hstore` as well?

Comment: `-x` means the same as `--extra-attributes` . I'm not using hstore.

Comment: What version of osm2pgsql do you use?

Comment: I use Verion 0.96.0. The issue is the same with osm.xml Data.

Comment: Similar issue has been fixed already into version 0.90 https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/137. Unfortunately the test data and style file are no more available. I suppose that you have checked that your osm.xml data contain osm_timestamps.

Comment: Yes, the data contains a timestamp: `<node id="197798" lat="36.0239247" lon="14.2884496" version="16" timestamp="2015-11-02T10:04:07Z" changeset="0"/>` | From http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/malta-latest.osm.bz2